# Delay after unlocking screen?

Tags: 22.04, lightdm, lock-screen

I'm running Lightdm on Ubuntu 22.04, and I've noticed that after I unlock my screen, my desktop appears, but it's completely frozen for about 15 seconds, which is frustrating.

Before, in 20.04, I was also using Lightdm, but this freeze didn't happen.

Why the delay in responsiveness after unlocking in 22.04? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

### Since the issue is related to the UI freezing, it might be due to graphics drivers

If you're using proprietary drivers (e.g., NVIDIA or AMD), ensure they are correctly installed and updated.

1. Use `lspci` Command, this command lists all PCI devices, including your graphics card.
2. Type `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3` in the terminal. This command will show your graphics card and the driver in use.
3. Go to "Software & Updates" and then to the "Additional Drivers" tab.
   This GUI tool will show you any proprietary drivers available for your system, including graphics drivers.
4. You can also use `ubuntu-drivers devices` to list proprietary drivers for all devices. This will include drivers for your graphics card if they are available.
5. Check Installed driver packages:
   For NVIDIA drivers, use `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`.
   For AMD drivers, use `dpkg -l | grep amdgpu`.

### Look at system logs

`/var/log/syslog` or `journalctl` for any errors or warnings that occur around the time you unlock the screen and copy the errors into your Question with [Edit].